# Reference request: microbenchmarking

Tags: reference-request

As microbenchmarking is a common method for the performance evaluation, I was expecting it to be extensively researched up to now. The search for related literature has not revealed much, hence I would appreciate for sharing relevant papers.

Examples of microbenchmarking frameworks: [criterion for haskell](http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/), [jmh for java](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), [benchmark for c++ from google](https://github.com/google/benchmark)

In general, references to literature about performance evaluation in practice are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a question about Theoretical Computer Science as defined in the Help Center.